# Instrumentation error running RoboElectric 2 tests in IntelliJ

Tags: android, intellij-idea, robolectric

I have a simple Android project that makes use of RoboElectric 2 and Maven.

I am able to run my tests fine using:

```
mvn clean test
```

but the tests fail to run inside IntelliJ IDEA . I get this strange error when attempting to run the tests from IntelliJ IDEA

```
Running tests
Test running startedTest running failed: Unable to find instrumentation info for: ComponentInfo{com.example/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner}
Empty test suite.
```

I get no other errors in the IDE and everything compiles and deploys to device correctly from within IntelliJ.

Comment: `com.example` looks weird, make sure you have the correct package specified in `AndroidManifest.xml` files.

Comment: I'm fairly sure my package is correct, otherwise the application would not run on device right? I'm using com.example, as well, an example.

Comment: as a test, see if you can run the unit tests from the command line and by pass intellij

Comment: As already mentioned in the question, the tests run fine from the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Unable to find instrumentation" suggests you try to run this as Android test - is it the case? It should be run as JUnit test (usage of RoboElectric suggests you've written standard unit tests)

Comment: Thanks! It should have been obvious to me.